# Use multiple double attributes to symbolize a line shape in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, fields-attributes

I need to represent multiple attributes to a line shape.

The attribute table already have the fields I need to represent. One of the attributes is the total number of commuters between cities; this must be symbolized by graduated symbols. The other one is the proportion of commuters in relation to the total population of the city of origin; I would like to symbolize this by graduated colors. The result, specially the legend, should look alike this picture:

[image]

Is there a way to do this on ArcGIS?

Ps.: using multiple attributes I figure out that the representation of the quantity by category is not the solution of the question, because what I need is something like "quantity by quantity", moreover, even if the quantity by category was the answer, the problem with the legend would remain unsolved.

Comment: Would you be able to add some more details to your question using its **edit** button, please?  For example, do the lines that you are trying to symbolize already have an attribute recording the population of the city of origin?  What have your attempts using [Multiple Attributes symbology](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s500000035000000) enabled you to achieve so far?